# code immediately stops responding (c, pointers, file I/O)

Tags: c, function, loops, pointers, file-io

I'm writing a code for homework that uses functions and pointers to read a file and fix the capitalization errors in it.

The goal is to read a pre-written file and fix it, adding line numbers to the beginning of each line. (i.e., tiTle -> 1. Title)

I think I've got the basic logic down, but there must be a bug that I'm not seeing, because it stops responding immediately after I compile and run it.

Here's my main() function.

```
FILE *casefixer;

casefixer = fopen("casefixer.txt", "r+");

char* ch;
int* char_in_word;
int* line_num;
*char_in_word = 0;
*line_num = 1;

while((fscanf(casefixer, "%c", ch)) != EOF){

    fscanf(casefixer, "%c", ch);

    fprintf(casefixer, "%d. ", *line_num);

    if(fix_caps(ch, char_in_word, line_num))
        fprintf(casefixer, "\n");

    fix_caps(ch, char_in_word, line_num);

    fprintf(casefixer, "%c", *ch);
}
fclose(casefixer);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
char* ch;          // uninitialized
int* char_in_word; // -||-
int* line_num;     // -||-
*char_in_word = 0; // dereferencing uninitialized pointer - undefined behavior
*line_num = 1;     // -||-
```

You don't have to use pointers when you see them in function declaration. If you're sure the function won't store them or try to allocate new memory for them, take an address of a regular variable:

```
char ch;
fscanf(casefixer, "%c", &ch) // ch is on stack longer than fscanf, everything's OK
```

Comment: Ok, I figured out the crashing problem, and I changed the fopen to w+ instead of r+. However, now it just clears the file and doesn't print anything. I haven't changed anything else.

Comment: Well, you want to read the file, don't you? Use `"r"` or `"r+"`. Of course it's undefined behavior if you didn't fix what I wrote.

Comment: Yeah, but I also have to re-write the file so that it's correct.  Hence, "w+".

Comment: There's something wrong with the while loop, and I can't figure it out. Any additional pearls of wisdom you can offer?

Comment: You have two fscanf's but are only looking at ch after one of them.

Answer (score 0):

1. By using "%c" you can only read a single character instead of a line. I recommend you use [fgets](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/) here.
2. The call of fscanf in the loop should be deleted since you've already called that in the `while((fscanf(casefixer, "%c", ch)) != EOF)`.
3. Writing while reading is not easy, especially when you want to rewrite what you've read before. You need to reposition your stream position indicator. So I think the better way should be you store your new file into a buffer and then write the buffer into the file.
4. In this two lines:

   ```
   if(fix_caps(ch, char_in_word, line_num))
       fprintf(casefixer, "\n");
   ```

   If I understand it right, you should use "continue" in this if statement.
5. In your code, the variable line_num is always 1. You should do the increment at the end of loop.

Comment: it increments inside the function when the character passed into it is '\n'